# How do I make sure an event happens after the thread calls wait()?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

I have the current `run()` method for a Golfer thread:

```
public void run() {
  while (done.get() != true) { // this is just a flag to see if the GolfRange is open
    synchronized (sharedStash) {

      System.out.println(">>> Golfer #" + myID
          + " trying to fill bucket with " + getBallsPerBucket() + " balls.");
      while (sharedStash.getSizeStash().intValue() < 5) {

        try {
          System.out.println(myID + "is still waiting, size = "
              + sharedStash.getSizeStash().intValue());
          sharedStash.wait(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Golfer.class.getName())
              .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }

      golferBucket = sharedStash.getBucketBalls();
      System.out.println("<<< Golfer #" + myID + " filled bucket with "
          + getBallsPerBucket() + " balls, size = "
          + sharedStash.getSizeStash());
    }
  }
}
```

`sharedStash` is an object that represents a collection of `golfBall` objects that is shared by Golfer and the thread that 'picks up' the golf ball at random times.

#### What I am trying to do:

Obviously if the size of the `sharedStash` is less than 5, the golfer can't pick up a bucket of balls and has to wait until the collector thread goes out and adds balls back to the `sharedStash`.

Say for instance the current `sharedStash` size is 3, and a `Golfer` thread 'Bob' is trying to fill up his bucket of balls. He has to wait until the Collector thread has collected balls from the field and add them to the `sharedStash`. But what is currently happening is that when the Golfer thread 'Bob' tries to fill up his bucket it just prints: "Golfer Bob is trying to fill his bucket" then the other threads that have balls in their buckets start hitting until the Collector Thread comes onto the golf range, collects balls, adds them to `sharedStash`. If the Collector adds more than 5, *what should happen is* Golfer Bob should get his bucket *before* any of the other Golfer Threads.

However, what is happening now is that some other `Golfer` will fill up before "Bob" even though bob has been waiting the longest.

How can I resolve this?

#### An example:

```
>>> Golfer #1 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
<<< Golfer #1 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 15
>>> Golfer #5 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
<<< Golfer #5 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 10
>>> Golfer #2 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
<<< Golfer #2 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 5
>>> Golfer #3 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
<<< Golfer #3 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 0
>>> Golfer #4 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
Golfer #1 hit ball #1 onto field.
Golfer #3 hit ball #16 onto field.
Golfer #5 hit ball #6 onto field.
Golfer #1 hit ball #2 onto field.
Golfer #2 hit ball #11 onto field.
*********** Bollie collecting balls   ************
*********** Bollie adding 5 balls to stash ************
*********** Bollie added 5 balls to stash ************
Current stash size: 5
Golfer #1 hit ball #3 onto field.
Golfer #2 hit ball #12 onto field.
Golfer #3 hit ball #17 onto field.
Golfer #5 hit ball #7 onto field.
Golfer #1 hit ball #4 onto field.
Golfer #2 hit ball #13 onto field.
Golfer #1 hit ball #5 onto field.
>>> Golfer #1 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
<<< Golfer #1 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 0
Golfer #2 hit ball #14 onto field.
Golfer #5 hit ball #8 onto field.
*********** Bollie collecting balls   ************
*********** Bollie adding 9 balls to stash ************
*********** Bollie added 9 balls to stash ************
Current stash size: 9
Golfer #5 hit ball #9 onto field.
Golfer #3 hit ball #18 onto field.
Golfer #1 hit ball #1 onto field.
Golfer #1 hit ball #16 onto field.
Golfer #2 hit ball #15 onto field.
>>> Golfer #2 trying to fill bucket with 5 balls.
<<< Golfer #2 filled bucket with 5 balls, size = 4
Golfer #1 hit ball #6 onto field.
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: Do you want assistance with _your_ code or some hints on how to solve the problem in the most elegant way?

Comment: Preferably assistance with my code, but an elegant suggestion would also be appreciated

Comment: I have also added sample output to show the problem. As you can see golfer 4 just continues waiting, but golfer 1 fills his bucket before.

Comment: Use a fair lock instead of just a synchronized block and a wait. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock%28boolean%29

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: Sorry, my internet connect sucks, the docs arn't loading...

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no effort to institute a queueing system. You want the golfers to wait in line, right? So, when it's time to go on line, *actually have the golfer join a line*, also known as a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Pass the `BlockingQueue` into each `Runnable` as part of the constructor. In this case, you don't even need to use the `synchronized` keyword, as you will block on the `poll` method. In other words, on the Golfer thread:

```
private BlockingQueue<Bucket> queue;

public void getMoreBalls() {
    queue.poll(ballQueue);
}
```

On the Bollie thread:

```
private BlockingQueue<Bucket> queue;

public void addBucketToQueue() {
   queue.offer(new Bucket());
   stash -= 5;
}
```

Obviously, this is not complete code, but I think you can flesh it out yourself.

Comment: This could work, but could I not just use a fair lock as stated @JB NIZET?

Comment: @Daniel I don't think it would be quite so easy as you think to do that. You have to ensure that the ordering stays valid, while still giving the lock to the Collector thread to be able to fill the stash. I don't recommend reinventing the wheel when data structures are provided that do the hard work for you.

Comment: You could improve your answer by talking about _fairness_.  Java's wait()/notify() mechanism makes no fairness guarantee.  Synchronization objects that _do_ guarantee fairness often, as your answer suggests, use queues.